# How AOT makes Android compilation better?

Tags: java, android, dalvik

Google replaced JIT compiler with Ahead-of-time (AOT) in Android version of Lollipop.

> Android Runtime (ART) with ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation and
>   improved garbage collection (GC), replacing Dalvik that uses
>   just-in-time (JIT) compilation

and according to Wikipedia,

> Ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation is the act of compiling a high-level
>   programming language such as C, or an intermediate language such as
>   Java bytecode, .NET Common Intermediate Language (CIL), IBM System/38
>   or IBM System i "Technology Independent Machine Interface" code, into
>   a native (system-dependent) machine code.

- how does it better than JIT which is used in previous version of
  Android.
- How it improved Android compilation process ?
- if it is better than JIT then why it is not used by Oracle for Java ?

Comment: "Better" is a hard word.  Different approaches might be more suitable for the mobile resource-constrained environment versus server environments.

Comment: "how does it better than JIT which is used in previous version of Android" -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation "How it improved Android compilation process ?" -- please edit your question to explain, in greater detail, what you mean. "if it is better than JIT then why it is not used by Oracle for Java ?" -- only Oracle can answer that, and they generally do not do so here.